# How to send a file from bot to user in chat using Bot Framework Composer?

Tags: .net-core, botframework, bot-framework-composer

- I have a bot which is built on composer.
- I want to send an excel file from bot to user in chat.
- I am using custom action for composer where I take text as input and create a file there. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-create-custom-actions
- Now I am unable to figure out that how to send a file to user so that he can download it.
- Currently, composer supports only upload of file not download.
- Is there any better way to make download functionality in bot using composer?

Comment: What channel is this bot running in? There are code samples for [handling attachments](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/15.handling-attachments) and [files in Teams](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/56.teams-file-upload). Did you try to use these?

Comment: The bot is running on teams channel, yes there are code samples but they are for .NET, and I am making bot in composer.

Comment: You mentioned the use of custom actions. Custom actions are code, and these are code samples. They might work for you.

Comment: @AayushGupta is that resolved?